# Sum text numbers in multiple cells

Tags: excel-formula

Here is the current formula I am using: =LEFT(F2,11)+LEFT(G2,11)+LEFT(H2,11)+LEFT(I2,11)+LEFT(J2,11)+LEFT(K2,11)+LEFT(L2,11)+LEFT(M2,11)+LEFT(N2,11).

Here is an example of the data in each cell:  $100,674.13 (-11%).

I am looking for a dynamic formula to extract the dollar amounts and sum them instead of using the formula above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `=MID(your_cell,FIND("$",your_cell)+1,FIND(" ",your_cell)-FIND("$",your_cell)-1)`.

It searches the position of the "$" +1 and returns the characters up to where it finds a space `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Use =SUM(MID(F2:N2,1,11)+1). Simple. Thanks for the help above.

Comment: This suffers from a couple of issues: 1) it gives the wrong answer (due to the `+1`) 2) it relyie on there being exactly 11 characters in the value 3) it will return an error if any of the cells don't contain a conforming value.  A version that doesn't suffer from these issues is `=SUM(IFERROR(--LEFT(F2:N2,FIND(" ",F2:N2)),0))`

Comment: For some reason when I tried this I got "0" (total is $1 million and change). You are correct if there are no characters in the cell there is a value error. The formula works with less than 11 characters though. Maybe your formula is missing something? Thanks.